# Is an .exe file generated when publishing a .net core console app in Linux?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

Does the .net console app published on Linux-x64 produce an .exe file like in Windows?

Comment: No, it does not produce an `.exe` file like in windows. Instead, you get a linux version of an executable.

Answer (score 2):

The .exe is windows supported file which is not support in Linux, if you select Linux when publishing the application, it will just generate the dll which you could use dotnet command in Linux to run this dll.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be! by default it will produce dll as mentioned in the other answer.

You can however force it to build an exe on linux by either setting a value in your csproj file

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

or updating your build command.Be aware however in dotnet 6 it will also bundle the framework with exe when this is set.

`dotnet publish project.csproj --configuration Release --runtime win-x64`